# Construct multidimensional array with array_push

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, php-7.3

Looking to construct below multidimensional array.
The first level-1 is ok, but the second is set to same level-1.

**Question:**

How can I direct the second foreach-loop to build the level-2, right under level-1 ?

**Wanted result:**

```
Array
(
    [id_no_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => title_1
        )

    [id_no_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => title_2
        )

)
```

**My attempt:**

```
<?php

// Position [Level-1]
$taxonomy_id = [
  "id_no_1",
  "id_no_2",
];

// Position [Level-2]
$titles = [
  "title_1",
  "title_2",
];

$array = [];

// Populate [level-1]
foreach ($taxonomy_id as $key => $value) {
  array_push($array, $taxonomy_id["{$key}"]);
}

// Populate [level-2]
foreach ($titles as $key => $value) {
  array_push($array, $titles["{$key}"]);
}


print_r($array);
```

**Result**

Array

```
(
    [0] => id_no_1
    [1] => id_no_2
    [2] => title_1
    [3] => title_2
)
```

Comment: You can not specify the key with `array_push`. You probably want to use pretty much the same syntax here, as was just explained to you under your other recent question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414697/

Comment: You want to take the key from one of your input arrays, and the value for the sub-array from the other input array - so you need to correlate both somehow, instead of looping through them separately. A `for` instead of a `foreach` loop might make more sense here, it will allow you to use the loop counter to access the corresponding values from both at the same time.

Comment: @CBroe Your suggestion fits best to the question, and is the most straightforward way. Please move the comment to an answer and I will approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take the key from one of your input arrays, and the value for the sub-array from the other input array - so you need to correlate both somehow, instead of looping through them separately.

A `for` instead of a `foreach` loop might make more sense here, it will allow you to use the loop counter to access the corresponding values from both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple solution for your problem with one foreach:

```
    foreach ($taxonomy_id as $key => $item) {
        $array[$item][] = $titles[$key] ?? null;
    }
```

Comment: `?? null` was a nice touch

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
$result = array_combine($taxonomy_id, array_chunk($titles, 1));
```

`array_chunk($titles, 1)` puts each of the title strings inside an array, then you can use the result of that as the values for `array_combine()`.

I do wonder where the original `$taxonomy_id` and `$titles` arrays came from, though. If possible I would rather look for a way to combine them at the time they're created instead of trying to stick them together like this.

Comment: smart solution but be careful `Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: @AlbertoMoro Yes, that is definitely important. But if both parameters don't have an equal number of elements we shouldn't be trying to do this to begin with because the results won't line up correctly regardless of how we do it, and if we can somehow know for sure that both parameters have an equal number of elements, then I think this probably could have been done more simply earlier in the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by nesting the two foreach:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($taxonomy_id as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($titles as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($key == $key2) {
            $array[$value][] = $value2;
        }
    }
}
```

You can test [HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73ce89f512329e37210dc9d03dc2292be66d7fb1)